# Escaping a character in a file name (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm having a problem where '/' character in the file is treated as a directory. To demonstrate the problem see below:

Example
The file name is :
Invoice 20/11/20.zip

I unzip it then do some modifications after that I re-zip it using the function below.

(the function doesn't really matter since it's working but I just put it to give context)

```
function zipDirectory(source: string, out: string) {
  const archive = archiver('zip', { zlib: { level: 2 }});
  const stream = fs.createWriteStream(out);
  return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    archive
      .directory(source, false)
      .on('error', (err: any) => reject(err))
      .pipe(stream)
    ;

    stream.on('close', () => resolve());
    archive.finalize();
  });
}
```

Let's say the out variable is named "./resources/Invoice 20/11/20.zip"

Is there any way to treat is as "Invoice 20/11/20.zip" not as a directory? If you have solutions please tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: Really, just name your files properly. That's the best advice I could give you. Most of the file systems do not support slashes as part of filenames.

Comment: I guess that's my last resort to change all '/' in the file name. Thanks for answering!